# How to change a blocking call in a loop to async call in Java

Tags: java, scala

I have the following code:

```
  List<Map<String, Object>> results =
          inputs.stream().map(this::get).collect(Collectors.toList());

  Map<String, Object> get() {

     Future<Response> resFuture = client.get(requests);  //scala API, returns scala Future
     Response res = Await.result(resFuture, deadline);
  }
```

How to change the above code to be Async instead? i.e., not using Await.result which blocks.

inputs.stream().map(this::get) is a sequential call IIUC. I want to make "client.get()" are done in parallel for each element in inputs, and then I can wait for all the responses to be ready for processing.

It looks Future.sequence might help here. But not sure how to implement that.

Comment: Using combinators like `map` & `flatMap`.

Comment: I do need the result of resFuture. However, in the current code, get() method is called in inputs.stream().map(this::get) where inputs is a list. In this case, the get() is called sequentially, and so does Await.result. I want to change it so that the retrieval (via client.get()) and processing response are done in parallel.

Comment: "Using combinators like map & flatMap." How? Example codes are appreciated.

Comment: You can't do both.  If you need the result _immediately_, then you must wait until there _is_ a result.  If you _don't_ need the result *yet*, then you can pass the `Future` off to the caller, who can decide if/when they care about the result.

Comment: inputs.stream().map(this::get) is a sequential call IIUC. I want to make "client.get()" are done in parallel for each element in inputs, and then I can wait for all the responses to be ready for processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result of the resFuture object, you will have to wait for it. There is no other go.

However if you do not want the result of the resFuture, then you can avoid calling the Await.result(...) itself. The callable class for which the future was returned will execute in the background no matter what.